# Why does a transform from polar coordinates using `TransformedField` not agree with by-hand calculation?

Tags: coordinate-transformation

I have the following (simple) system of ODE's that I wish to express in Cartesian coordinates:

\begin{align*}
r' &= r(1-r)\\
\theta' &= 1
\end{align*}

Working it out by hand, by differentiating $x = r\cos\theta$, $y = r\sin\theta$, I find

\begin{align*}
x' &= r' \cos\theta - r \sin\theta \theta' \\
   &= r(1-r)\cos\theta - r\sin\theta \\
   &= x(1 - \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}) - y\\
\\
y' &= r' \sin\theta + r \cos\theta \theta' \\
   &= r(1-r)\sin\theta + r\cos\theta \\
   &= y(1 - \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}) + x
\end{align*}

However, using `TransformedField` like so:

```
TransformedField["Polar" -> "Cartesian", {r (1 - r), 1}, {r, \[Theta]} -> {x, y}]
```

the result is:

$$\left\{x \left(1-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)-\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}+y \left(1-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)\right\}$$

So does the disagreement come from an error in my calculation (which I have been unable to find), or a misuse/misunderstanding of `TransformedField`?

Comment: Please, avoid using $\LaTeX$ as it is impossible to copy-paste the results you have provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When applied to a `List`, `TransformedField` assumes that the elements are components along the **unit vectors** of the original coordinate system. That's not the case in your equations, because they are derivatives of the coordinates themselves.

So you're using `TransformedField` where it shouldn't be used. Instead, you can use the chain rule directly as follows:

```
With[{
  j = CoordinateTransformData["Cartesian" -> "Polar", 
    "InverseMappingJacobian", {x, y}],
  mapping = 
   Thread[{r, θ} -> 
     CoordinateTransformData["Cartesian" -> "Polar", 
      "Mapping", {x, y}]]},
 j.{r (1 - r), 1} /. mapping]

(* ==> {-y + x (1 - Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]), x + y (1 - Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])} *)
```