# Transforming a StreamPlot from polar to Cartesian

Tags: graphics, pattern-matching

I have a function that transforms a `ContourPlot` with arguments given in polar coordinates into the desired plot in Cartesian coordinates, like so:

```
f[r_, th_] := r^2 Sin[2 th]
g[r_, th_] := {r Cos[th], r Sin[th]}
pl = ContourPlot[f[r, th], {r, 0, 3}, {th, 0, Pi/2}, 
        ContourShading -> None];
pl[[1, 1]] = g @@@ pl[[1, 1]];
pl
```

Now I would like to do the same with a `StreamPlot`, but the corresponding graphics object has a more complex structure. If I do

```
sp = StreamPlot[{4 r Cos[2 th], -4 r Sin[2 th]}, 
    {r, 0, 3}, {\[Theta], 0, Pi/2}, StreamStyle -> Darker[Pink]];
```

I can see that the crucial part is `sp[[1, 2, 1, 3]]`, which has a structure like

```
{{Arrowheads[{{0.02000000000000001, 1.}}], 
  Arrow[{{3., 1.5437002295175233}, {2.9890855215045633, 
   1.543115802641102}, {2.9591182838349264, 1.5414321353734735}, 
   {2.9294510170829717, 1.5396817289664542}, {2.9000823597142626, 
   1.5378607501076507}, {2.8710109501943655, 1.53596536548467}, 
   {2.8422354269888443, 1.5339917417851185}, {2.813754428563265, 
   1.5319360456966038}, {2.7855665933831917, 1.5297944439067321}, 
   {2.7576705599141897, 1.5275631031031103}, {2.7522285961973623, 
   1.5271047868205019}}]}..
```

so I would like to replace the coordinates in the `Arrow` functions by their Cartesian transforms. I tried something like

```
sp[[1, 2, 1, 3]] /. 
 Arrow[{{r_, th_}..}] -> Arrow[{{r Cos[th], r Sin[th]} ..}]
```

but I can't get my pattern for the sequence of repeating arrow points right. Perhaps there's also a nifty use of `Apply` (as in the case of the contour plot above) that will work, but my problem is that I don't understand the syntax well enough.

Can someone
(a) help me fix my code, and
(b) explain exactly how to use `Apply` or an appropriate rule to do what I want?

Comment: `sp /. Arrow[p_] :> Arrow[Function[{r, th}, {r Cos[th], r Sin[th]}] @@@ p]`?

Comment: @Michael E2: Hmm, it's doing something, but the plot looks wrong. I tried `StreamPlot[{r, \[Theta]}, {r, 0, 3}, {\[Theta], 0, Pi/2}]` with this, and it definitely isn't right.

Comment: I don't understand what I am seeing right now. Simple tests like `StreamPlot[{r, 0}, {r, 0, 3}, {th, 0, Pi/2}]` and  `StreamPlot[{0, 1/r}, {r, 0, 3}, {th, 0, Pi/2}]` look perfectly fine, but the case with `{4 r Cos[2 th], -4 r Sin[2 th]}` as the vector field definitely doesn't look right. I need to think about this.

Comment: If you're trying to plot the vector field `{4x, -4y}`, then you've got an extra `r` in the theta component. `Solve[{Dt[x] == 4 x, Dt[y] == -4 y} /. {x -> r Cos[t], y -> r Sin[t]}, {Dt[r], Dt[t]}] // TrigReduce`. (See [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80376/why-does-a-transform-from-polar-coordinates-using-transformedfield-not-agree-w/80399#80399).)

Comment: @Michael E2: I must have some stupid error somewhere. I have the streamfunction `psi[r_, \[Theta]_] := r^2 Sin[2 \[Theta]]`, which, with `vr = 1/r D[psi[r, \[Theta]], \[Theta]]`, and `vth = -D[psi[r, \[Theta]], r]` gives `4r Cos[2 \[Theta]]` and `-4r Sin[2 \[Theta]]`, respectively, for the vector field. However, if I drop the factor `r` for the second component, I get a plot that looks about right. Trouble is, that factor r should be there, I think...

Comment: Isn't the displacement differential $(dr, r\,d\theta)$? So `vr` is $dr/dt = \partial\psi/(r\,\partial\theta)$ and `vth` is $r\,d\theta/dt = - \partial\phi/\partial r$?

Comment: Yep, that's it; I just had that thought while munching my cereal. My vth  is the tangential velocity, but I need to give StreamPlot the angular velocity to integrate streamlines in the r-theta plane. So, yep, I need to divide the second component by the radius.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three ways:

```
sp /. Arrow[p_] :> Arrow[Function[{r, th}, {r Cos[th], r Sin[th]}] @@@ p]
sp /. Arrow[p_] :> Arrow[p[[All, 1]] Transpose[Through[{Cos, Sin}[p[[All, 2]]]]]]
sp /. Arrow[p_] :> Arrow[CoordinateTransform["Polar" -> "Cartesian", p]]
```

The second is fastest by a little bit and arguably the most obscure. The third is roughly 400-700 times slower than the other two but readable.

```
(* OP's sp, fixed per comments *)
sp = StreamPlot[{4 r Cos[2 th], -4 Sin[2 th]},
  {r, 0, 3}, {th, 0, Pi/2}, StreamStyle -> Darker[Pink], 
  GridLines -> {Range[5]/2, Range[6] Pi/12}]

polarbackground = PolarPlot[0, {t, 0, Pi/2},
   PolarAxes -> True, PolarAxesOrigin -> {0, 3.}, 
   PolarTicks -> {"Radians", Automatic}, PolarGridLines -> Automatic];

Show[
 polarbackground,
 psp = sp /. Arrow[p_] :> Arrow[Function[{r, th}, {r Cos[th], r Sin[th]}] @@@ p],
 PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 3}}]
```

[image]
  
[image]

---

*Update: Join close arrows*

```
arrowsp = Cases[psp, Arrow[p_] :> p, Infinity];
distance = 0.0012;
newarrows = FixedPoint[
    Function[{arrowsp},
     arrowsp /. With[
       {nf = Nearest[arrowsp[[All, 1]] -> arrowsp]},
       Cases[arrowsp, p_ :> With[{q = nf[Last@p, {1, distance}]},
           {p -> Join[p, First@q], First@q -> Nothing} /; q =!= {}],
         1, 1] /. {r_List} :> r]
     ],
    arrowsp
    ];

Show[
 polarbackground,
 psp /. Append[Arrow[p : {First[#], __}] :> Arrow[#] & /@ newarrows, _Arrow -> {}],
 PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 3}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks again, and I like that `polarbackground` ;-) As a minor quibble, you can see that there's issues near `r=0`. I can fix that simply by staying a little bit away from `r=0`, which is acceptable, but I wonder if there's a more elegant way to do this. And, yeah, I know, this is to be expected due to the singularity of the transform at r=0.

Comment: @Pirx You're welcome. One might quibble more and say that things are deformed too much when `r` is small. (Too many arrowheads even on the next line away from the origin.) I'm surprised it worked so well. In my experience `StreamPlot`  is very hard to control, so many things being done automatically. You might try playing with `StreamScale`.